# IBM Appcenter console apk fails to upload

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have 2 questions on deploying mobile first apps to the appcenter.

What I did:
Installed eclipse then Mobile First 6.3 studio, followed the IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core and finally the appcenter.

All installed no problems. Setup a MobileFirst server configuration and a runtime following the instructions on [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_ov_server_install.html)

What didn't work:
Added an android environment to  my project, built it and tried to add the apk. Got the "file not uploaded" message, appear next to the upload field. Was happy to find some responses here.

What I have tried:
I have tried to increase max_allowed_size from 256 to 500 then 1000 in my.ini. No change, then I tried pointing to the right aapt.exe in the server.xml, that didn't help, commented out the aapt line and still nothing.

Also I am finding my apk in the the /android/native/bin and not apps/bin as the documentation and I think a few on here have pointed out. Any idea what I might have missed?

Not sure where to go from here. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

I have the following setup:
Eclipse + Mobile First Studio
IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core
IBM Mobile First Platform Server + a config and runtime deployed.
Appcenter Console
Running on an average machine with Windows server 2008 r2 and a mysql db.

Thank you any help would be much appreciated.

Logs from \IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\sigmaServer\logs (I hope these are right ones)

console.log

```
[12/8/14 23:03:00:811 CET] 00000012 SystemErr                                                    R 8814  WorklightManagementPU-mysql  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[12/8/14 23:03:00:889 CET] 00000012 SystemErr                                                    R 8892  WorklightManagementPU-mysql  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Though you are using optimistic transactions, OpenJPA is now beginning a datastore transaction because you have requested a lock on some data.
[12/8/14 23:03:00:904 CET] 00000012 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader                I Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11216 ms
[12/8/14 23:03:00:904 CET] 00000012 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I MobileFirst Administration Services servlet context listener initialized
[12/8/14 23:03:00:920 CET] 00000012 ht.admin.listeners.WorklightManagementServletContextListener I FWLSE3199I: ========= MobileFirst Administration Services version 6.3.0.00-20141127-1357 started.
[12/8/14 23:03:01:029 CET] 00000012 org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet          I The system is using the com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementServiceServlet JAX-RS application class that is named in the javax.ws.rs.Application init-param initialization parameter.
[12/8/14 23:03:01:341 CET] 00000012 apache.wink.server.internal.application.ApplicationProcessor I The following JAX-RS application has been processed: com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementServiceServlet
[12/8/14 23:03:01:357 CET] 00000012 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Resources                I The server has registered the JAX-RS resource class com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.ManagementService with @Path(/).
[12/8/14 23:03:01:372 CET] 00000012 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers                I The class com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.ByteArrayWorkaroundProvider was registered as a JAX-RS MessageBodyReader provider for com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.ByteArrayWorkaround Java types and */* media types.
[12/8/14 23:03:01:372 CET] 00000012 org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Providers                I The class com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.ByteArrayWorkaroundProvider was registered as a JAX-RS MessageBodyWriter provider for com.ibm.worklight.admin.util.ByteArrayWorkaround Java types and */* media types.
[12/8/14 23:03:02:511 CET] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet                              I SRVE0242I: [wladmin] [/wladmin] [ManagementServlet]: Initialization successful.
[12/8/14 23:03:02:527 CET] 00000012 com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction     A CWWKZ0001I: Application wladmin started in 20.264 seconds.
[12/8/14 23:03:13:696 CET] 00000038 com.worklight.core.ilmt.WorklightILMTLogger                  I FWLSE0277I: Creating an ILMT record in the file 'C:\Program Files\ibm\common\slm\85a30bb123bab8037ee6e789807592ae.slmtag'.
[12/8/14 23:04:13:366 CET] 00000037 SystemErr                                                    R Exception in thread "Thread-20" 
[12/8/14 23:04:13:366 CET] 00000037 SystemErr                                                    R java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up.120 secs.
[12/8/14 23:04:13:366 CET] 00000037 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.worklight.core.init.WorklightServletInitializer$1.run(WorklightServletInitializer.java:121)
[12/8/14 23:04:13:366 CET] 00000037 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:410 CET] 000000b4 com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService                      I file uploaded
[12/8/14 23:16:19:628 CET] 000000b4 com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AAPT                           I Resolving APK without AAPT
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R java.io.IOException: Expected chunk of type 0x11c0200, read 0x1200200.
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.ReadUtil.readCheckType(ReadUtil.java:32)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidResourceParser.readPackage(AndroidResourceParser.java:80)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidResourceParser.read(AndroidResourceParser.java:62)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AndroidAPKResolver.resolve(AndroidAPKResolver.java:138)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AAPT.getMetadata(AAPT.java:362)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.fileUploaded(UploadService.java:158)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.__fileUploadedJSON__(UploadService.java:109)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:706 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:722 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 SystemErr                                                    R  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService                      E Exception during resource upload. null
[12/8/14 23:16:19:737 CET] 000000b4 com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService                      E {
    "id": "86ba5d65-f9d9-44d9-8d91-692106bdfbb1",
    "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
    "productVersion": "6.3.0.00-20141127-1357"
}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:614)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.putAll(UploadService.java:326)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.fileUploaded(UploadService.java:158)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.__fileUploadedJSON__(UploadService.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
    at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Messages.log puts this post over the limit, let me know if that would help troubleshooting though.
And thanks.

Comment: Server logs from a failed upload?

Comment: Hi added the section from the console.log in my edits from the logs folder  (\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\sigmaServer\logs).

Comment: Hi Idan, should I past the entire log? I just pasted the relevant time stamps from when I tried the upload last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue that will be fixed as soon as possible: if an APK built with latest Android 5 (level 21) is uploaded to the Application Center console and the AAPT tool is not used to decode the APK metadata (cf "Resolving APK without AAPT" trace), the upload is failing with a exception in the server log.

To fix this issue, set up your server to use the AAPT tool from the Android SDK as described in the documentation: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_configuring_websphere_application_server_for_appcenter_manually.html
Step 9.

You have to set the android.aapt or android.aapt.dir JNDI property.

Hope this helps

Comment: this solution didn't fix my problem .

Answer (score 0):

After downloading this two libraries it will work fine.

**zlib.i686** and **libstdc++.i686**

Regards,
Mahdi.