# MobileFirst Platform AppCenter apk upload fails

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-appcenter

I have set up a MFP 6.3 server on RHEL with Tomcat and Oracle. The app center has been deployed successfully. If I try to upload an apk file, the console tells me that the upload failed.

Here is the server log (Catalina.out):

```
Mrz 24, 2015 1:30:57 PM com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService fileUploaded
INFO: file uploaded
Mrz 24, 2015 1:30:57 PM com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService fileUploaded
SEVERE: Exception during resource upload. Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Mrz 24, 2015 1:30:57 PM com.ibm.puremeap.util.PureMeapUtil serverError
SEVERE: {
"id": "e75830a8-43a0-436c-a77c-8f619aa4a45c",
"message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
"productVersion": "6.3.0.00-20150106-1717"
}
java.io.IOException: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1879)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1923)
at com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AAPT.getMetadata(AAPT.java:269)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.fileUploaded(UploadService.java:158)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.UploadService.__fileUploadedJSON__(UploadService.java:109)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:56)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:339)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

"Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden" means File or directory not found.

The server.xml has the android aapt properly defined:

```
 <Environment name="android.aapt.dir" value="/app/inet/app/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

The apk has been tested with another installation of MFP Appcenter and was uploaded successfully, so it seems to be a different problem [than this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366781/ibm-appcenter-console-apk-fails-to-upload)

The installation folder of MFP (/app/inet/app/IBM/MobileFirst_Platform_Server/) is owned by a different user. So I added permissions to the android-sdk directory, but upload is still not working. I assume that there is a temporary file that gets created in a directory where the user does not have permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set CATALINA_TMPDIR to "/tmp" in my setenv.sh and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

Sebastian explained already his solution for Apache Tomcat, but let's explain a bit the context:

App Center needs to create a temporary file, but its creation failed. App Center uses the default temporary directory of your operating system which is specified by the system property java.io.tmpdir. On UNIX systems the default value of this property is typically "/tmp" or "/var/tmp"; on Microsoft Windows systems it is typically "C:\WINNT\TEMP".

Apache Tomcat modifies java.io.tmpdir according to CATALINA_TMPDIR. If this points to a directory that does not exist, you see the mentioned error. Therefore setting CATALINA_TMPDIR to a directory that exists and that has write permissions solves the problem.